# JavaScript if statement won't work for some reason, have tried everything but no idea what's wrong

Tags: javascript

Probably a really simple mistake, because I'm quite new to JavaScript:

```
<head>
<title>
Test
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
if document.getElementById('one').checked = function() {
document.getElementsById("TestDiv").innerHTML = "one";}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="one" id="one" value="one" />
<div id="TestDiv">Test</div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @TedHopp When the radio button is selected the div text will change from "Test" to "One", just testing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parentheses and don't include a function in the if statement:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (document.getElementById('one').checked) {
        document.getElementById("TestDiv").innerHTML = "one";
    }
};
```

And you misspelled the `getElementById` method the second time. There was an extra `s` character.

If you want this event to happen when you select the radio button, then use:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('one').onclick = function () {
        // if (this.checked) {
        document.getElementById("TestDiv").innerHTML = "one";
        // }
    };
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PbST6/

Comment: Good catch on the extra 's'.. +1

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working for me for some reason.

Comment: @HarrisonGarner Well, you didn't explain what you wanted fast enough :) When you commented on your question earlier, we learned what you wanted to happen. After that, I updated my answer with new code and a demo. Check that out, it seems to work

Comment: Second one worked great! Thanks :) and yeah sorry about that, will learn for next time haha

Comment: @HarrisonGarner No problem :) Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to set an event handler for the element with `id="one"`, this code should do it:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('one').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("TestDiv").innerHTML = "one";
    }
}
```

If you just test the `checked` state of the element when the window is loaded (like you appear to be trying to do), it won't respond to user events.

Comment: There's no reason to check if it's checked. If you click a radio button, it will be checked

Comment: @Ian - True. I didn't notice that it was a radio button. If it were a checkbox, the test would be needed.

Comment: Absolutely :) Just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is formatted wrong...

```
if (document.getElementById('one').checked) {
    document.getElementById("TestDiv").innerHTML = "one";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
window.onload = function() {
  if(document.getElementById('one').checked) {
    document.getElementsById("TestDiv").innerHTML = "one";
  }
}
```

The conditional part of the "if" has to be in (). In this case the conditional is "document.getElementById('one').checked"
Then what you want to happen if the condition is true is in { }, not in a separate function